# Columns in Multidimensional Arrays c#

Tags: c#, arrays, file-import

I have data in txt like this:

flea,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,6,0,0,0,6

frog,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,4,0,0,0,5

frog,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,4,0,0,0,5

I need to count the number of zeros in a chosen column, for example in the first column there are 3 zeros.

Here is my code so far:

```
        //data patch
        string[] tekst = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\zoo.txt");


        //full of array 
        string[] tablica = tekst;



        for(int s=0;s<tablica.Length;s++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tablica[s]);
        }

        //----------------Show all of array---------------------------//


        //----------------Giv a number of column-----------------////
        Console.WriteLine("Podaj kolumne");

        int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        //Console.WriteLine("Podaj wiersz");

        //int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int n = tablica.Length;

        int m = tablica[a].Split(',').Length;

       string[,] liczby = new string[n, m];

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            int suma = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
            {
               //somethink should be here

            }

        }
```

Any ideas for solving this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  What problem are you having?

Comment: Please include text as text, not as an image.

Comment: i don't know how to count this zeros as you see i have no idea what to put in the second for() and txt is added as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
//data patch
string[] tekst = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\zoo.txt");


//full of array - you allready have a string[], no need for a new one
//string[] tablica = tekst;



for(int s=0;s<tekst.Length;s++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(tekst[s]);
}

//----------------Show all of array---------------------------//


//----------------Giv a number of column-----------------////
// try to use names with some meaning for variables, for example instead of "a" use "column" for the column 
Console.WriteLine("Podaj kolumne");
int column = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

// your result for zeros in a given column
int suma = 0;

// for each line in your string[]
foreach ( string line in tekst )
{
    // get the line separated by comas
    string[] lineColumns = line.Split(',');
    // check if that column is a zero, remember index is base 0
    if ( lineColumns[column-1] == "0" )
        suma++;
}

Console.WriteLine(suma);
```

**EDIT: Just make sure to validate that the column they ask for, really exist in your array, AND if you do not consider the first column as the one with the name, adjust this part**

```
lineColumns[column] // instead of lineColumns[column-1]
```